# Jquery datepicker: highlight 'today' when clicked?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, highlight

I have a jquery datepicker on the site, the calendar is always visible. My problem is I cannot seem to select 'today'. Well, I can, but it doesn't change its highlight as the other days do, it always keeps its 'today-look' and this is pretty confusing.

1. Is there some built-in way how to highlight today when selected (as the other elements are)? <- preferred
2. Is there a way to easily hide today's highlight with js?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the jquery ui css.Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/abhMH/)

```
/*selected date */
.ui-state-active{
 color:red !important;
}
/*todays date*/
.ui-state-highlight{
   border:none !important;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How could I apply the same style as for the 'default' selected state? Do I have to do it manually all?

Comment: [try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+remove+ui-state-highlight): http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/2/