# jQuery ui datepicker: Remove yellow highlight on (unhighlight) today's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How do you remove the yellow highlight on datepicker's today's date? I was able to do it when my datepicker is called via an input field (got it from here: [Jquery datepicker: highlight 'today' when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508545/jquery-datepicker-highlight-today-when-clicked#comment25541821_17508686)), but cannot when it is called via div (inline = true)

My reason for this is I am using custom timezone and if I have a different today's date based on the timezone it still highlights the today's date of my local computer.

Here is the code that worked using an input field:

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                inst.dpDiv.find('a.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add your code which you have tried...

Comment: Use css and overwrite the classes you want.

Comment: @gino , why dont u override its CSS classes ,and apply !important in your custom CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/48/)

```
.ui-state-highlight{
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3/*{borderColorDefault}*/ !important;
    background:#e6e6e6/*{bgColorDefault}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlDefault}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgDefaultRepeat}*/!important;
}
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active{
     border:1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorActive}*/ !important;
    background:#ffffff/*{bgColorActive}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlActive}*/ 50%/*{bgActiveXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgActiveYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgActiveRepeat}*/!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes in your code:

**HTML**

```
Date: <div inlineEditable="true" id="datepicker" ></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(document).find('a.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
             }, 100);
          } 
    });
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).find('a.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
     }, 100);
});
```

**DEMO**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/57/)

**[UPDATE]**

I did some new change, used `onSelect` method for same.

Comment: But this is still highlighting today date.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - Please check my updated answer. i should do this before. thanks for the update.

Comment: Hi @ShailParas when I click on a different date on mouse release I still see a highlight on the date today before it changes color

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.ui-state-highlight` css class with `.ui-state-default` in jquery-ui.css like below :

```
.ui-state-highlight,/*added this with ui-state-default */
.ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default 
{ 
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3/*{borderColorDefault}*/; 
  background: #e6e6e6/*{bgColorDefault}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlDefault}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgDefaultRepeat}*/; 
  font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/; 
  color: #555555/*{fcDefault}*/; 
}

.ui-state-highlight,/*added this with ui-state-default */
.ui-state-default a, 
.ui-state-default a:link, 
.ui-state-default a:visited 
{ 
  color: #555555/*{fcDefault}*/; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abhMH/50/)**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by very simple way: I've just removed all css rules of ui-state-highlight class from jquery.ui.css. Current date are higlighting with black border by adding only one css rule to ui-state-highlight class:

`.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: black !important;
}`

But I used only one date picker ui widget in my project.